# YA book about a girl who goes to a school for kids with special powers, then runs away

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I probably read this book around 2010-2012. It was a free Amazon book I downloaded on my Kindle.

- There was a girl who had special powers (I'm vaguely sure that she didn't know exactly what they were yet though).
- She went to a school where all the other kids also had powers and she had a little group of friends.
- Something about her made her a target from a bad group so she was forced to go on the run (from what I remember it was the head of the school who actually told her to run and hide and sent her away with her group of friends).
- One of the boys in the group had the power that if he held someone's hand and shut his eyes he could transport them (mentally not physically) to anywhere they wanted and it would feel as though they were there.
- I think he and the girl maybe had something going on romantically.
- I remember there being some quite cool fight scenes. One was like they were found in a room they were renting and had to escape to the car but the girl got hurt quite badly.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that one too, pretty sure it's "[The Ultimate Sacrifice](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11432092-the-ultimate-sacrifice)" by Talia Jager!

[image: Front cover of The Ultimate Sacrifice]

> Kassia is a 16-year-old girl just trying to have a normal life. This is somewhat difficult because she has the ability to inflict pain on others with her mind, which is why she was sent to a special institute for kids with various gifts. It is here Kassia met her best friend Mira. Their lives will change forever after Mira is attacked and Kassia finds out her talent is much more powerful when she saves her. Little did she know that this act would attract the attention of demons. Suddenly, she is on the run from them with her boyfriend, Mira, and a few of their close friends. Realizing she can't outrun the demons, she seeks the guidance of a shaman. The shaman tells her the heart breaking news that the only way to protect her friends and the institute is through her own death. Join Kassia on her journey of friendship, love, and the conflicts she must face to protect those around her. The Ultimate Sacrifice is recommended for grade 9 and up. The Ultimate Sacrifice is the FIRST book in The Gifted Teens Series. Roots and Wings is the SECOND book in The Gifted Teens Series. Unbreakable is the THIRD book in The Gifted Teens Series.

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find [tips on how to write a good story identification answer and what details to add in our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/7957).